# Use semaphore to stop thread in timer from execution

Tags: java, thread-safety, scheduledexecutorservice

I have the following java code, that uses the ScheduledExecuterService. Basically, there are two important calls made in this method: 1. the integrationMonitor.Processor(...) and 2. the runIntegrationSynching() methods.

The scheduler will make sure that these methods execute according to the time interval. Recently however, I've had the problem where processing of these two methods are very long. If the user then sets the timer interval to too low, the next processing cycle will start, even before the previous one finished.

Someone here suggested I use semaphores to do the synchronization, and I did -  it works for one of my test cases, but not the other one.

I am using a semaphore to prevent a new schedule cycle to start, if a previous one is still busy. How can I know when a thread finished so that I can release the semaphore?

Here is the code:

```
static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
      semaphore.acquire();
    catch(InterruptedException e1) {}

    runIntegrationSynching();

    try {
      semaphore.release();
    } catch(InterruptedException e1) {}

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            IntegrationMonitor intgrationMonitor = new IntegrationMonitor();
            try {
              semaphore.acquire();
            } catch(InterruptedException e1) {}

            intgrationMonitor.Processing(configXML, rcHost, alarmMonitorMap, blocker);
            try {
              semaphore.release();
            } catch(InterruptedException e1) {}
            if(intgrationMonitor != null){
                intgrationMonitor = null;
            }
        }
    };

    LOGGER.info("Attempting to start the thread for RC " + rcHost + ". Thread ID:" + thread.getId());
    thread.start();

}   
},2,2,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: since they are threads, you can put some semaphore so that only one thread could acquire it and only that can process.

Comment: Will this prevent the timer from executing on the next scheduled timer interval? I guess if I put the semaphore declaration outside of the timer it can work, otherwise it will just create multiple semaphores.

Comment: yes, please put it outside. or you can have a static semaphore which is already constructed, but acquired & released by the threads.

Comment: Thanks. I've never used semaphores before. Could you please look at my edited version and help me out?

Comment: read some examples of semaphores+java, try for yourself and see some failures and fix them.. you will internalize it, which is better than me helping you out.

Comment: hi @a3.14_Infinity - just letting you know that I am still stuck on this despite trying different options.

Comment: could you check this? https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-thread-mutex-and-semaphore-example/